# SharePoint Windows logging - account was successfully logged on 4624 - why so frequent?

Tags: error, security, windows-authentication, logging, connection

My company has a centralized logging platform for all servers. We recently noticed that the bulk of our events come from SharePoint servers for successful logon events. If I look at "Event Viewer" -> "Security" on a SharePoint app server, I am seeing hundreds of events per second, which adds up to millions per week, and quickly grows into Terabytes of what seems to be useless information. Is there a way to track down why these connections are being made so frequently, or even better, to have SharePoint maintain connections or do some sort of connection pooling so we're not logging so much? The message typically contains the following key information:

```
An account was successfully logged on.

Impersonation Level: Impersonation

Security ID:  DOMAIN\*VariousSharePointServiceAccounts* (*or sometimes a user account*)

Event ID: 4624

Logon Process: Kerberos

Workstation Name: (end user's workstation name or another server in the farm)
```

Comment: To answer your ultimate question, no there's nothing you can do about it besides configure your software to ignore these events outright. But what is going on here is just simple impersonation. Since you likely have a significant use of SharePoint, you'll see these requests for authentication [attempts].

Comment: @TrevorSeward That's unfortunate. These records take up so much space! This does seem unusual in my case in that there are just about as many records overnight when no one is using SharePoint as during 'business hours'. Perhaps there is some process running that doesn't need to be?

Comment: SharePoint is always doing something (timer jobs, service recycles, etc.). Nothing you can do about it. Either discontinue logging detailed events on the SharePoint servers or reduce the Security event log size.